# Integrating Firebase Analytics into Xamarin iOS spams logs with keychain warnings

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios, firebase-analytics

I just integrated the Firebase Analytics SDK into my Xamarin iOS app. However, now it's spamming the logs with:

> 2019-06-13 16:00:44.728870-0400 orgnarrprmobiledev[8450:341429] 5.16.0
>   - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID023003] Couldn't create keypair from Keychain OSStatus: -34018 2019-06-13 16:00:44.729602-0400
>   orgnarrprmobiledev[8450:341429] 5.16.0 -
>   [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID023004] Could not update attributes of the
>   key pair to be accessible after first unlock. update status: -34018
>   2019-06-13 16:00:44.730314-0400 orgnarrprmobiledev[8450:341429] 5.16.0
>   - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID023004] Could not update attributes of the key pair to be accessible after first unlock. update status:
>   -34018 2019-06-13 16:00:44.731801-0400 orgnarrprmobiledev[8450:341429] 5.16.0 - [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID010003] Unable to generate keypair. 2019-06-13 16:00:44.731947-0400
>   orgnarrprmobiledev[8450:341429] 5.16.0 -
>   [Firebase/InstanceID][I-IID010009] Keypair could not be loaded from
>   Keychain. Error: Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=2005 "(null)"
>   2019-06-13 16:00:44.732061-0400 orgnarrprmobiledev[8450:341429] 5.16.0
>   - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS020001] Failed to get InstanceID: Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=2005 "(null)"

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this? I tried enabling Keychain access in my Entitlements.plist, however it still spams the same warnings.

Comment: This is on simulator right?

Comment: @IvanIčin Correct, I should've mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior on the simulator. Simulator doesn't support the KeyChain.

Comment: Is there a way to at least squash the warnings so that the simulator logs aren't flooded? It may be expected behavior but it's not acceptable behavior.

Comment: See if someone else knows how to do that. I can only tell you that you need the real device if you want the KeyChain to work, that is certain.